# How to get count of a relation data in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a Post, like and comment model

I want to get the Post data, comments data and count of likes in a post using relations in laravel.

Everything is working but from the below code i'm getting the likes array and I want the count without any looping.
Is this possible with the Relation?

This is my PostController code with relation:

```
$posts = Post::with('user','comment')->get();
```

Post model:

```
public function comment(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function like(){
    return $this->hasOne(Like::class);
}
```

Like Model:

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Comment Model:

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: ```$posts = Post::withCount('user')->withCount('comment')->get();```

Comment: Shouldn't post have many likes?

Comment: @Tpojka You are right

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$posts = Post::withCount('user')->withCount('comment')->get();
```

[LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `withCount()` helper with an array :

```
Post::withCount(['comment'])->get();
```

If you want you can customise your count :

```
Post::withCount([
    'user',
    'comment as comments_today_count' => function($query){
           $query->where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays()

     }])->get();
```

You should also use plural for your hasMany relationships :

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

so that you can use it more explicitly :

```
foreach($post->comments as $comment){...}
```